# Where should I put a script that needs to execute once when the user logs in graphically?

Tags: fedora, gnome, shell-script, login, gnome3

Using Gnome 3 on Fedora 15, where should I put a script that needs to execute once when the user logs in graphically?

Comment: FYI, the script I have will mount some network drives that are used for software development.

Comment: Why doesn't ~/.profile get executed when you do graphical log in?

Comment: That depends on your display manager (the program where you type your user name and password, e.g. xdm, gdm, kdm, …) and your session manager (which probably is part of a desktop environment, e.g. Gnome, KDE, Xfce, …), as well as how your distribution configured them. What display manager and desktop environment are you using?

Comment: @Gilles, IMO I already stated "default fedora 15" so that should tell you what display manager.

Comment: When I do `ps -ef | grep gdm` I get:
root      1117     1  0 15:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/gdm-binary -nodaemon
root      1142  1117  0 15:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gdm-simple-slave --display-id /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Display1
root      1156  1142  0 15:16 tty1     00:00:53 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -background none -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-8pX5qs/database -nolisten tcp vt1
root      1402  1142  0 15:16 ?        00:00:00 pam: gdm-password

(Also `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` returns `gnome`.) Given the output, I think that means default fedora 15 runs gnome display manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user logs into the graphical mode, the predefined desktop environment starts (Gnome 3 in your case). This is the software package that should be used for setting up and configuring anything that is to be started *when the user logs in graphically*.

---

First create the script, place it in some private place like `~/scripts/` or `~/bin/` and make executable (`chmod +x script_path_and_name.sh`). Then, from Gnome ***System*** menu select ***Preferences***->***Startup Programs***. Click *Add* on the right of the list, type any name you want and point *Command* to the script you just created.

<sub>I was translating all the menu entries back to English from Polish, so please correct me if I made a mistake there. (My girlfriend's computer is the only one around that has Gnome installed :) )</sub>

Comment: FYI, I edited the question to show "gnome 3".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using F15, your profile file is

> ~/.bash_profile

instead of

> ~/.profile

So, see if that file exist and edit it adding your script

Comment: The only shell that reads `.bash_profile` is bash, and if that file is not present, it reads `.profile`.

Comment: also ~/.bash_profile will only execute for shell-login not graphical login. (i didn't downvote tho...)